# Populate parent instance

Tags: c#, oop

I have a parent class, like this:

```
public abstract class Business<T> : IBusiness<T> where T : Entity
{
    protected Data<T> data;

    public IEnumerable<T> Select(DataContext db)
    {
        return data.Select(db);
    }
}
```

And I need to populate the instance of the "data" member on the child clas.

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
public class UserBusiness : Business<User>
{
    public UserBusiness()
    {
        data = new UserData();
    }
}
```

I wonder if there are some other methods.

I also used an abstract function in the parent class link this:

protected abstract Data GetData();

To force the child class passing the instance.

Which is the best approach? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a dependency injection framework (e.g. Ninject).  Register all your child and data classes with the framework,  and the framework will take care of building the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an abstract constructor:

```
public abstract class Business<T> : IBusiness<T> where T : Entity
{
    protected Data<T> data;

    Business<T>( T _data) 
    {
        data = _data
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Select(DataContext db)
    {
        return data.Select(db);
    }
}
```

Then call it in the derived constructor:

```
public class UserBusiness : Business<User>
{
    public UserBusiness() :
        base (new UserData())
    {

    }
}
```